# Can I set the password expiry limit for mariaDB existing user?

Tags: linux, mariadb

I want to set the password expiry limit for existing user(root) on mariaDB(5.5.53).
Can I set it? 
If it is available, how can I set it?

also
I know that how I set password expiry limit for existing user(root) on mySQL.
Is it same way completely?
Thank you.

Regards,

Comment: What do you mean by password limit? Limit number of characters, or time limit (expiry)? What is your point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know this has not been implemented in MariaDB.

The mysql.user table has the field 'password_expired' but the MariaDB documentation states "MySQL-compatibility option, not implemented in MariaDB".

You could write a simple shell script that changes the password every ** days and run it using cron.

EDIT:

Source: [https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-7597]